# Filter array of object by un overlapped key

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

How to filter the object by un overlapped keys?

example:

```
const array = [{"0-3":"abc"},{"1-4":"abc"},{"5-8":"abc"},{"8-11":"abc"}]
```

in the above overlapping `arrays = [{"1-4":"abc"},{"8-11":"abc"}]` (those start with previous end key);

expecting result: `const array = [{"0-3":"abc"},{"5-8":"abc"}]`;

I got no idea. any one help me? ( I am getting the values from backend)

Answer (score -2):

Hints

#### Try extracting the keys

Use `Object.keys`

#### Split the keys into start and end values

Use `.split("-")`

#### Keep updating a value of the highest end value accepted

Then if the start value of a newly arriving key is too low, do not accept it.

If it is not too low, accept it and update the "highest end-value accepted" variable

#### Try coding this and show us what you have done

Then we can give you further feedback